# SQL Server 2016 - Server crash

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2016, sql-server-2016

I did a fresh installation of a SQL Server Standard 2016 on Microsoft Windows Server 2016.

During the installation and manually starting the database engine service i get the following error:

```
Windows could not start the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service on Local Computer

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

I tried changing the credentials under which the service runs to Local Service, User Account and the Administrator account

manually starting the SQL Server binary (sqlservr.exe) via command line i get the following error:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application.
```

The event log has the following event:

```
Faulting application name: sqlservr.exe, version: 2015.130.1601.5, time stamp: 0x5724ae45
Faulting module name: sqllang.dll, version: 2015.130.1601.5, time stamp: 0x5724aebe
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000016bdc00
Faulting process id: 0x13ec
Faulting application start time: 0x01d23f479dbf612a
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqllang.dll
Report Id: 05e65b0f-778c-4bb2-8be6-6fcb17b91bf2
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I tried to do a clean install of the SQL Server, but it results in the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ISO we retrieved was corrupt.

After redownloading the ISO and comparing the SHA1 checksums from both ISOs i noticed a difference between them.

Altough the installation went fine.. It seems the installer does not verify itself and the installed files.

Redownloaded the ISOand everything works fine now!